# How can I replay the tutorial?

Tags: warframe

I skipped the intro/tutorial the first time around... how can I go through that again?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With Update 9 a new intro/tutorial based on the E3 Trailer was added to the game and the option to replay it.

To replay the Tutorial open your profile page in game by pressing the xp/credits/platinum bar and you will now see a Tutorial button.

Comment: Outdated answer